# If an (infinitely) large flat surface plane pushes thru air slowly, what kind of sound wave is formed?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, flow

On a string/rope, a wave requires an source that oscillates up and down. The wave's frequency and wave length depends on the source. A loud speaker can produce a tone thru oscillation with its membrane vibrating back and forth. Now, I found myself dumbfounded by the scenario as the title, as the source is exerting force but not oscillating. Assume that sound travels faster than the flat surface plane, so I guess some information must travel ahead of the surface with the speed of the sound, but is it a wave with some frequency? or is it just one expanding pressure front like snow accumulating in a snowplow? I don't even know what terms to google with.

Please DO NOT write down any equations right away, please start with the microscopic interaction of air molecules, then move on to the macroscopic ensemble behavior. Feel free to use imprecise language and analogies, I want the first image that comes to your mind, NOT the equations. This question is not asking "Describing the waves, ie. its frequency or wavelength if the surface is moving this fast", I am simply trying to have an intuitive view of the interactions that started the waves.

Comment: You are asking for imprecise language on a physics community, and for no equations to be used.

Comment: *"Now, I found myself dumbfounded by the scenario as the title"* - I am too. Why the stipulation that the flat surface is *infinite*?

Comment: @ChemiCalChems yes, before the Newton's law of gravity, the learnt crowd had a hunch it would be a inverse square distance equation. I want that "hunch". Both of the theories of relatives started with "what if" ideas, I want ideas like those. If you are a student trying to pass a test, by all means equation away. I don't need you to waste your time here.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri if it is not infinite, there may be side air flows on the edges of the surface, that complicates the picture too much.

Comment: eliu, OK, I suppose I can see what you're getting at. I'm reminded (for some reason) of the so-called ['infinite' baffle enclosure for loudspeakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudspeaker_enclosure#Infinite_baffle). Of course, the baffle isn't actually infinite in extent but it's an appropriate approximation in a limited context.

Comment: I don't get this community. If you can't even describe something with plain English, how do you describe it with highly accurate and concise language that is Mathematics?

Comment: @eliu English words are slippery.  There can be so many meanings to them.  For example, while I'm writing an answer I'm considering the Fourier transform of your plate's movement.  It's occurring to me that when you want to talk about the frequencies of the waves, we need to talk about the exact way the plate starts movement.  That is lost in the English, but is very clear when you start to try to do equations.

Comment: @eliu We failed to describe something in plain English because as other people have said, it's not as precise a language as math is. Also, take into account physicists come from all over the world, speaking English or maybe not. The power of mathematics as a "universal language" if you will, is what makes us default to it for everything we can. We aren't dumb people, of course we can attempt to explain subtleties in English, but mounting up a complete reasoning for a complex physical phenomenon mostly in actual language hasn't been standard since Newton's Principia.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you consider to be a "wave."

The plane is clearly moving into the volume of air, exerting some force on that air.  Divide that force by the surface area and you get pressure (in your infinite case, you'll have to take the limit as the area approaches infinity, or just start with the concept of pressure).  The plate will exert some pressure on the air, forcing air molecules to move.

Now the physics purist would say that you can take the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of this signal to get into frequencies, which is what your question asks for.  But when going down that route, funny details emerge that take the form of equations.  Is this a steady state case where the plate has been moving forever, or is this plate just starting to move?

In all of these cases, the general shape you'll see is something exponential like.  There will be a sharp decrease in pressure as one moves away from the plate which exponentially decreases in intensity as you move further away.  The exact shape of this cannot be stated without putting the plate's motion into an equation.

Most people do not consider an exponential function like this to be a "wave," but a purist will.  Indeed, we rely heavily on exponential functions when we do Laplace transforms of systems.  But that's what it will look like: a roughly exponential pressure decrease, becoming smaller as you get further away from the plate.

Comment: I would argue that what is a wave is quite standardly defined, it should be a solution to the wave equation.

Comment: Thank you, I was definitely not asking about the "frequency components" of "deconstruct of a spatial domain wave shape using Fourier transform". Please read my first sentence in my question, a wave on a rope depends on the oscillating source, in this case, a steady state constantly moving surface, according to your answer there won't be a wave, but pressure simply piling up like snow in a snowplow.

Comment: So, from "sound that human can hear" perspective, we probably can't hear anything, I believe ear needs oscillation to register anything. Now, this exponential shape, I assume the highest value is there the plane surface is. But does this highest value change? I think it does, if the surface move infinite time, value could go infinite?. Also, how far does your lowest value go on the "distance x" axis? what if the question is asking steady movement of the plane for 10 mins, your exponential function can't just stretch infinitely to x axis, information can't travel faster than the speed of sound.

Comment: @eliu In the real world, pressure cannot go to infinity.   Something will get in the way.  What you describe is what happens when one breaks the sound barrier, where the theoretical pressure can build up to infinity, but the assumption that sound travels in waves breaks down.  Supersonic and hypersonic aerospace engineers have to worry about this stuff.  You asked to not have equations, but the equations for exponential decay do permit a finite pressure at the surface hwile still extending to infinity.

Comment: @eliu As for the second part, that is an example of why we need equations.  What I described was the steady state solution.  The transient solution is typically computed using Laplace transforms.  And you are correct that, with finite time to propagate, the pressure gradient generated will have finite length.  However, practically speaking, the waves that are 10 minutes ahead of a plane are so extraordinarily weak that it'd be impossible to measure the difference... we're talking ideals at this point.

Comment: The sudden movement is actually easier for the human ear to hear (although I doubt any of the situations in your mind would register, from a practical point of view). The pressure differences could potentially rise fast enough to impart energy into the hairs in the cochlea, and they *do* vibrate at a frequency, even if they are stimulated by something that's not oscillating.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems If I were permitted equations, then I would agree with you.  But when we explicitly forbid the equations needed to be precise, we have to consider that different people may have different intuitions as to what is and is not a wave.

Comment: @CortAmmon I've already expressed my opinion in a comment to the question. Being forbidden the use of equations in a physics community is like being denied gas at a Formula 1 race.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems Yabba Dabba Doo!

Comment: @eliu Oh, and I missed one of your questions.  The lowest distance you'll think of this way is a few nanometers.  The concept that's important is the "mean free path length," which is the average distance a molecule can travel before colliding with another.  Once you're working on the scale of at least a few mean path lengths, the statistical behavior of the gas leads to the wave behaviors we expect from fluids.  Smaller than that and you have to start paying attention to the individual particles.

Comment: That's what happens in a shock wave.  Usually we assume that "pressure" describes the movement of molecules from all sides.  However, when you get past the speed of sound, that assumption stops being a reasonable one.  You end up with "sonic" flow on one side (slower than the speed of sound), "sonic flow" on the other with respect to the supersonic body, and in between is a nasty boundary layer called a shock wave where air simply stops behaving the way you or I expect it to.

Comment: If writing down equations make this much more clear, by all means please describe exact what the wave in spatial domain is like at t = 10 sec, while the plane is traveling at 100m/s.

Comment: @CortAmmon One interesting thing you mentioned is that "use laplace transform to calculate transient state". The only place I learnt laplace is in control system. I don't have full intuition of the math, but I believe laplace is just a quicker way to solve differential equations. So the solution should be transient+steadystate right?

Comment: In effect, it is a "purely near field pseudo-wave".

Comment: @The_Sympathizer "Purely near field" is a pretty sound description of the effect. I like it.  Although, describing what that phrase means without equations could be dicey.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, a very low frequency, mixed frequency, sound wave forms.

You have slightly stumped me by saying

> please start with the microscopic interaction of air molecules, then move on to the macroscopic ensemble behavior. Feel free to use imprecise language and analogies, I want the first image that comes to your mind, NOT the equations.

because what I am best able to do is describe, not the equations themselves, but what they mean. The sound wave is simply the solution of the equations. One can also think of it as a pressure wave.

The individual air molecules are not important. Their motion is random thermal motion, described by the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. But a very large number of individual molecules go to create a volume element, which is still extremely small, and in which individual thermal motions can be ignored. The equations of wave transmission (and indeed the Navier-Stokes equations from which these equations can be derived) apply to volume elements, not to individual molecular motions.

Ok, so you describe volume elements, and you apply Newton's laws, and basically you get the Navier-Stokes equations. Then a solution is the wave transmission of pressure waves, which is exactly what we mean by sound waves. That is to say, it is a wave if it is a solution of a wave equation. Which it is, and which is where I am stumped because I don't know any other definition of a wave. A wave satisfies a wave equation. And the equations generated by the transmission of pressure due to the moving plate are wave equations.

A good analogy is to think of the bow wave (and stern wave) of boat. The pressure generated by the boat moving through the water creates a wave which flows away from the boat. Likewise the pressure generated by your flat plate generates a wave which moves ahead of the plate.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I have the exact same feeling as you do on "another definition of wave besides wave equation". the bow wave is ... not a good analogy, it is something visual, it doesn't let you feel what a wave is. I don't personally know why the bow wave is just not working out for me. Electron spin, Magnetic flux, those are analogies, they work really well for me.

Comment: nonetheless, just to confirm one detail here: the solution of the wave equation will not be just one exponential shape (like snow piling up in a snowplow), but will have some sinusoidal components in it, meaning like a bow wave, there will be repetitive patterns (frequency)

Comment: @eliu, wave equations have sin waves as solutions, then the general solution is a sum of sinusoidal components, generated either by initial conditions, or, as in this case, by a forcing term (the movement of the plate. Likewise the bow of a boat generates the forcing term)